# what is PAT (Pre Acceptance Testing)?

Tags: testing, terminology

What is exactly PAT, When we will do the pre acceptance testing?

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is not within the scope of questions appropriate for this site, as defined in [What topics can I ask about here?](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Please also see: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](//stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) You may be able to get help on [another Stack Exchange site](//stackexchange.com/sites#name). However, be sure to read each site's on-topic page prior to posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's a widely-used term or part of a standard. Therefore, what exactly it means is organization-specific and should be defined in a glossary somewhere. More likely though you'll just have to ask people what it means.

Answer (score 2):

Any testing done before acceptance testing.

This would include:

- Unit tests
- Stress tests
- Integration tests
- Performance tests

Answer (score 1):

There's no standardised meaning for the term - often it depends on your process-  be it Agile or Extreme Programming etc.

Generally however, there are a number of tests done by developers or testing in a developer test environment.  This can be unit tests, developer tests, sanity regression tests, performance tests - ie tests that the QA team wants done before they'll even look at it.  At a bare minimum, it might be just testing that the software builds (although it's frightening how often I've had a developer fail to even check this).

Answer (score 0):

Well I would like to share something which everyone may not agree to but this is what I feel Pre-Acceptance testing would be:

The testing done to perform that the system under test functions as per the designed requirements to cover the customer's business areas before entering the User Acceptance Test phase where users from the customer's side are invited to perform the testing at the vendor's location where development team assistance is available when any flaw occurs in the expected business flow. This will be called as Alpha Test. Please feel free to correct me if I have said something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Acceptance testing is a testing technique performed to determine whether or not the software system has met the requirement specifications. In SDLC, acceptance testing fit as follows:

```
Requirement Analysis - Acceptance Testing
High Level Design - System Testing
Low Level Design - Integration Testing
Coding - Unit Testing
```

Simply put, PAT is any test done before acceptance testing. There are various forms of acceptance testing such as User acceptance testing, business acceptance testing, alpha testing and beta testing.